# Probability or optimization

Tags: probability, optimization

I have a problem with the following case

$F$ and $G$ are distribution function on $x\in{[0,1]}$ and they have same mean $\mu$

I want to prove
$\int_0^1 F(x)G(x)dx\geq(\mu-1)^2$

Comment: By "distribution function" you mean the cumulative distribution function (CDF) or the probability density function (PDF)? Capital letters make me guess the first one, but I like to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is just the continuous version of [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_sum_inequality), since: 
$$ \mu = \int_{0}^{1} x\,f(x)\,dx = \left. x F(x)\right|_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}F(x)\,dx $$
gives:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}F(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}G(x)\,dx = (1-\mu),$$
and both $F$ and $G$ are weakly increasing functions.

Comment: Thanks Jack yes I meant CDF and what you did is great